# Linear congruence $53x \equiv 62 \pmod{105}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all solutions that aren’t congruent to each other in modulo $105$ of

$53x \equiv 62 \pmod{105}$

I’ve know that this equation has $1$ solution, because $(53 , 105) = 1$. But, how can I find that solution without brute-forcing?

Comment: Sorry , I added what I know.

Comment: http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/exeucalg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x\equiv 106x \equiv 62*2 \equiv 19 \pmod{105}$

Answer (score 0):

$53^{-1}\cong2\bmod{105}\implies x\cong 2\cdot62\cong124\cong19\bmod{105}$.